# Default data in fact table

Tags: etl, data-analysis, data-warehouse, star-schema-datawarehouse

I have the ff. DB table 'proposal' and 'funds' that will be transformed into a dimension (dim_proposal) and fact (fact_funds) tables. Cardinality of 'proposal' to 'funds' is zero-to-many and 'funds' to 'proposal' is one-is-to-many.

My question is should i generate fact data representing a proposal row with zero funds? In the source system, there is no generated rows for zero funded proposal. Kindly provide best approach and practices for this kind of scenario.

Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what kind of fact “funds” is.

Comment: A star schema should be designed based on your reporting requirements not the structure/contents of any source data. If you have defined your requirements then you should be able to answer your question as to what data you need in your fact table

Comment: Hi @NickW one of the business requirement is to identify proposals per target location (funded and unfunded). Location data is also a dimension connecting to the fact fund table.

Comment: Hi @DavidBrowne-Microsoft the fund fact contains data on the allocated funds for the proposal including sources, amount allocated, target location.

Comment: Sir @NickW should i generate a default fund value for zero fund representation?

Comment: I don't know. Its entirely dependent upon whether your requirements require it or not in order to be able to answer the questions your DW needs to be able to answer